# How do I get the set of rectangles from a k-d tree?

Tags: geometry, kdtree

If you look at the Wikipedia entry for [k-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), you will see this [illustration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aKdtree_2d.svg) of points and planes that divides the 2D space into rectangles.

My question is how do I get the resultant set of rectangles? I thought that each 'path' to a leaf node might give me the bounds. Is there a general way to do this for N points at arbitrary depths?

Notice that what I am not asking for is a k-d tree of hyperrectangle structures, where the given input is a set of rectangles that can then be queried for range search, etc. My input is a set of random points, and I want to output the set of rectangles that 'tesselate' or subdivide the Cartesian space completely.

Comment: There seem to be two questions here. Are you looking for an algorithm that constructs a k-d tree from a random set of points, or an algorithm that, given a k-d tree, enumerates the set of partitioning rectangles? Or both?

Comment: k-d trees do not generally store rectangles, they store split axes.  You could trivially implement this by writing a small bit of rectangle splitting code that basically passes in a 2D rectangle that each node cuts along the split axis, sending the 2 new rects to the children.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks eh9 for the edit. Just to clarify the input is the k-d tree constructed from a set of random points, the output is the set of resulting rectangles.

And thanks to Jerdak for the 'trivial' solution:
Indeed just walk down the tree starting at the root node and keep splitting rectangles at each axis depth. The only additional piece of info is the outer bound of the original rectangle. Once all nodes are visited, you can return the complete set.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of kD-Trees actually store the bounding hyperrects of each subtree/leaf so that better pruning can be done in KNN searches. Note, these aren't rectangles that cover all of the space, but rather leave gaps between leaves where there aren't any points. Personally I think they are cooler ;-)